# Jekyll alias to static file

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a Jekyll blog at `example.com` and want the path `example.com/doc` to point to a static file (a pdf, in particular). Jekyll alias generators seem to work only for individual posts, not static files.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Create a directory 'doc' in your root.

Step 2. Create an index.html in this directory with a meta redirect in the head like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>You are being redirected</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=filename.pdf">
</head>
<body>You are being redirected... if not, <a href="filename.pdf">click here</a>.</body>
</html>
```

Step 3. Put the filename.pdf file next to your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

alias `alpha/beta` => `omega`

1. Create folder `_alpha/beta`
2. update _config.yml

```
includes_dir: _alpha

collections:
  alpha:
    collections_dir: _alpha/beta
    output: true
    permalink: /omega/:name
```